# Curl falls back to tlsV1

Tags: curl

we have a serious issue with Curl falling back to tlsv1 even though it forced to use v1.3

```
curl -vvv --tlsv1.3 --tls-max 1.3 --resolve <domain>:443
```

i tried 6 times to reach the dst and one session was terminated.
from pcap i can i see that on the forth attempt it suddenly uses tlsV1.
what is going on here ???

VER : curl 7.68.0
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i am downloading a file using Curl and forcing it ti use tlsV1.3.
as shown at the pcap above suddenly ( on the forth attempt) it decides to run with TLSV1 and the connection is terminated (expected since the server not supporting V1)